# How to prevent one2many field on wizard opening by itself in Odoo12?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have this wizard for printing payslips which has 2 one2many fields: payslips and employees.

When i click Print -> pdf is downloaded but one2many field opens by itself. So a form for adding payslips or employees opens up again.

This doesn't happen always, it seems to be in about 50 percent of cases, with no rule to why it is happening. Also sometimes it opens payslips and sometimes employees, again with no rule which will open.

Is this a know bug or does anyone know a fix for this?

Also this seems to be happening on all wizards which have one2many field and do some kind of printing.

I tried debugging python code line by line to see where this is called but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Could you provide the involved python code please ?

Comment: I trust you that this could be happening, maybe due to js extensions or who knows, to fix it you will need to debug a lot of js code in order to find the cause and remediation of that behavior

Comment: There is really no code involved since it happens on all wizards, some print PDFs and some Excel files. I haven't noticed this behavior anywhere other than printing. So the printing happens and than one2many form for choosing opens again.